# MS Access. Проверка на изменения БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, криптография, хеширование, ms-access

Вопрос почему хэши измененных БД не меняются при изменении данных в самой БД. У меня есть папка с несколькими БД, в другой папке точно такие же БД. После этого хотелось бы изменить в первой папке некоторые БД, чтобы выдавало сообщение о том, сколько БД были изменены. Есть два таких метода:

```
void RecoveryEachOfDBs()
    {
        FileInfo fn;
        string path1 = @"C:\Databases";
        string path2 = @"C:\CopyDB"; 
        DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(path1);
        DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(path1);
        MD5 hash1 = MD5.Create();
        MD5 hash2 = MD5.Create();
        string[] hashDB = new string[dir1.GetFiles().Length];
        string[] hashRec = new string[dir2.GetFiles().Length];

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dir1.GetFiles().Length; i++)
            hashDB[i] = GetMd5Hash(hash1, dir1.ToString() + "\\" + dir1.GetFiles()[i]);

        for(int i =0; i< dir2.GetFiles().Length; i++)
            hashRec[i] = GetMd5Hash(hash2, dir2.ToString() + "\\" + dir2.GetFiles()[i]);

        for (int i = 0; i < hashDB.Length; i++)                
                if (hashDB[i] != hashRec[i])
                    count++;

        MessageBox.Show("Количество измененных БД");
    }

    static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
    {
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: вы хеши по пути к файлу считаете что ли?

Comment: @tym32167 да. указываю путь. и рассчитывается хэш файла. неправильно? я запутался, блин

Comment: Допустим ваш файл лежит по пути c:\file.db. Вы добавили изменения в файл - путь изменился? нет. А раз путь не изменился, то и хеш пути не изменился. Чтобы знать, какие файлы были изменены, надо считать хеш не для пути файла, а для всего содержимого файла

Comment: `byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));` => `byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(input));`

Comment: А не проще дату изменения файла сравнивать?

Comment: @tym32167 Все равно не получается. После изменения все равно хэши одинаковые

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да мне надо это, чтобы вести контроль целостности

Comment: `dir1` и `dir2` указывают на один и тот же `path1`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ахахххаххаха, сам только что заметил, прежде чем сюда снова заглянул. Какой я идиот. Спасибо большое, что время потратили

Comment: хех, точно `DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(path1);`=> `DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(path2);`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо вам огромное

Comment: Пожалуйста, хорошо, если помогло :)